# dev-sda2.device takes longer during boot in Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10 than other distros. How to fix this?

Tags: boot, mount, systemd, fstab

/dev/sda2 is my root partition. I'm using an SSD and it's not worn out. dev-sda2.device doesn't take more than a second in pop os or archlinux.

This is my `# systemd-analyze blame`:

```
7.558s dev-sda2.device                                      
2.829s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
1.077s snapd.service                                        
 659ms ufw.service                                          
 570ms networkd-dispatcher.service                          
 305ms dev-loop0.device                                     
 297ms udisks2.service                                      
 285ms dev-loop2.device                                     
 277ms dev-loop1.device                                     
 266ms accounts-daemon.service                              
 248ms dev-loop3.device                                     
 244ms mnt-Multimedia.mount                                 
 244ms systemd-logind.service                               
 237ms dev-loop4.device                                     
 212ms dev-loop5.device                                     
 204ms avahi-daemon.service                                 
 203ms NetworkManager.service                               
 200ms polkit.service                                       
 196ms fwupd.service                                        
 179ms switcheroo-control.service                           
 173ms thermald.service                                     
 170ms apparmor.service                                     
 170ms wpa_supplicant.service                               
 116ms snap-snapd-11036.mount                               
 115ms systemd-journald.service                             
 115ms systemd-resolved.service                             
 112ms snap-snapd-11107.mount                               
 111ms upower.service                                       
 109ms gpu-manager.service                                  
 109ms ModemManager.service                                 
 109ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount               
 108ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount              
 107ms snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                         
 101ms grub-common.service                                  
 100ms secureboot-db.service                                
  93ms systemd-journal-flush.service                        
  91ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
  85ms e2scrub_reap.service                                 
  84ms apport.service                                       
  84ms snap-core18-1988.mount                               
  83ms keyboard-setup.service                               
  80ms systemd-udevd.service                                
  79ms rsyslog.service                                      
  78ms user@1000.service                                    
  74ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
  63ms systemd-modules-load.service                         
  60ms snapd.apparmor.service                               
  50ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
  47ms gdm.service                                          
  41ms swapfile.swap                                        
  38ms geoclue.service                                      
  31ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
  28ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
  27ms kerneloops.service                                   
  26ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2B34\x2d5EB7.service
  26ms plymouth-start.service                               
  21ms systemd-random-seed.service                          
  21ms snapd.seeded.service                                 
  20ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
  20ms modprobe@drm.service                                 
  20ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
  19ms systemd-remount-fs.service                           
  18ms colord.service                                       
  16ms pppd-dns.service                                     
  15ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
  15ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
  14ms alsa-restore.service                                 
  13ms systemd-sysusers.service                             
  12ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
  11ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
  11ms boot-efi.mount                                       
  10ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
   9ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
   9ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
   9ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
   9ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
   8ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
   7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
   7ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
   6ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
   4ms openvpn.service                                      
   4ms console-setup.service                                
   2ms setvtrgb.service                                     
 816us snapd.socket
```

This is `# systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
    The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @11.177s
└─multi-user.target @11.177s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @9.214s +21ms
    └─snapd.service @8.136s +1.077s
      └─basic.target @8.103s
        └─sockets.target @8.102s
          └─snapd.socket @8.102s +816us
            └─sysinit.target @8.095s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @8.035s +60ms
                └─apparmor.service @7.862s +170ms
                  └─local-fs.target @7.861s
                    └─boot-efi.mount @7.850s +11ms
                      └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2B34\x2d5EB7.service @7.822s +26ms
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2B34\x2d5EB7.device @7.820s
```

This is my fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=e2d712b5-14ca-4f71-9f81-5bda06ef8e8c /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2B34-5EB7  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
LABEL=Multimedia /mnt/Multimedia auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

(btw, Multimedia is the name of my HDD - /dev/sdb)

How to fix this?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to get your boot time down from 11.177 seconds to ... ?

Comment: @Matigo I wanted to say that why is dev-sda2.device taking so long? In my experience with most other distros it takes about a sec on average. So, it should take about 4.619s

Answer (score 1):

Removing snapd by

```
sudo apt remove snapd
```

fixed it.

Note: This will remove snaps from Ubuntu